# Exporting all windchill usernames

Tags: excel, vba, ptc-windchill

I'm looking for a way to export all the usernames in the windchill system. Ultimately the goal probably will be to import those names into an excel spreadsheet. Any suggestions?

As a side note, (and please forgive me if I misuse terms here), what possibilities are there to access Windchill using VBA. My impression is that because there is no VBA API, my options for accessing data stored in windchill from Excel are limited.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can get all Windchill users and usernames by designing a query
  using `QueryBuilder`.

  Go to site->utilities and Report Management.There you can add your
  query then generate a report and you can have the option of exporting
  that report in excel format. Or you can do this through windchill
  API,

  query all users by using

  `QueryResult userQuery=PersistenceHelper.manager.find(new QuerySpec(WTUser.class));`

  From this you can able to get the username then write that to excel
  sheet by using plain java code.
- You can connect your Windchill with all microsoft office applications
  by installing Windchill Desktop Integration.

  You can install Windchill Desktop Integration from **Quick Links** ▶
  **Software Downloads**. After you accept the license agreement, the **Software Downloads** page appears. Under **Setup and Installation**, click **Windchill Desktop Integration** or
  **Windchill Desktop Integration (64-Bit)** depending on your computer’s operating system.

  **Note**

  *For information about versions of Microsoft applications supported by Windchill Desktop Integration refer to the software matrix by
  using the following
  URL:*http://www.ptc.com/partners/hardware/current/support.htm. *If
  you cannot access the software matrix, see your administrator for
  this information.*

  Refer help center for more details on how to configure windchill menu
  in MS Office applications.I don't any idea about `VBA`api's for
  windchill.

Answer (score 2):

```
    QuerySpec qs = new QuerySpec(WTUser.class);
    QueryResult qr = PersistenceHelper.manager.find(qs);
    WTUser user = null;
    while(qr.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Persistable output = (Persistable) qr.nextElement();
        user = (WTUser) output;
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }
```